# Getting random Blank email while using nested while loop

Tags: php, mysql, email

1st, I know mysql_ is outdated and I should use mysqli (unfortunatly, I inherited this system and its way too much work to change it over at the present time)

The problem I have is when I execute the code, I am getting random blank emails.  This system loops through a list of stores in a database and lists the information in a table for the store managers.  It doesnt really matter what information is being presented.    Does anyone see anything right off hand that micht cause this problem?

```
while($store = mysql_fetch_array($result_store)){

#Updates the Report Date for each store in the Loop
$report_date = "UPDATE ActiveStores SET Report_Date = '$Today' WHERE StoreNumber = $store[StoreNumber]";

if (!mysql_query($report_date, $con)){
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}


#Selects data from ActiveStores for the current store in the loop
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ActiveStores WHERE StoreNumber = '$store[StoreNumber]' ORDER BY StoreNumber");

#Loops through the currently selected store and Creates an Array of the data
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
    #Sets Store Variable

        $Store = $row['StoreNumber'];
    echo '<table width="1110"><table width="1102"><tr>';


    # To Email Address 

    #$emailaddress = '******@*****.com';

    # Message Subject 
        $emailsubject= 'Testing Report - Store: ' . $Store;

    #Turn on Output buffer for email
    ob_start();
    #Heading for Report
    echo '<h2 class="blktext">Walgreens Weekly Report - ' . $Today . '<br /></h2>';

    echo '<h2>Insurance Orders:</h2>';


#Cancelled Orders for the store this week   
    $result_cash_canceled = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE StoreNumber = '$Store' AND Cancel = 'checked' AND Order_Type = 'Cash' AND Cancel_Date > '$Sevendaysback'");
    $tot_ord_ins_prt = mysql_num_rows($result_cash_canceled);


    if ($tot_ord_ins_prt !== 0){
        echo '<h4 class="blktext">Cancelled Orders for the store this week</h4><span class="blktext">';
        echo '<p><i>Fitter Action:  Fitter to contact client to notify of cancelled order, if not initialed by client.</i></p>';
        echo "<table border='4' class='rpttbl' frame='hsides' rules='rows' width='1400'>";
        echo '<tr><th>Store #</th><th>Order #</th><th>Customer</th><th>Phone #</th><th>Cancel Date</th width="150"><th>Reason for Cancellation</th><th width = "150">Patient Notified<th></tr>';
        while($row_cash_canceled = mysql_fetch_array($result_cash_canceled)){

            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td align='center'>" . $row_cash_canceled['StoreNumber'] . "</td>";  
            echo "<td align='center'>" . $row_cash_canceled['Order_ID'] . "</td>";  
            echo "<td align='center'>" . $row_cash_canceled['Cust_First_Name'] . " " . $row_bo['Cust_Last_Name'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td align='center'>" . $row_cash_canceled['Cust_Phone'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td align='center'>" . $row_cash_canceled['Cancel_Date'] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td align='center'>&nbsp;</td>";
            echo "<td align='left'>( ) Called: Patient Cancelled notified<br />( ) Called:  LVM for Patient</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
        echo "Total: " . $tot_ord_ins_prt;
        echo'</span>';
    }





    #Message at bottom of email
    echo '<br /><br /><br /><br /><p>Thank you for your prompt attention to this report.</p>';
    echo '<p>If this report is blank in all the above sections, this means, at this point, we are not showing any active orders within our system.<br />';                              
    echo 'If you feel this is in error, please contact our Customer Care team at:  <strong>(***) ***-8125</strong></p>';
    echo '<p>Please update this form with the appropriate action taken by patient, and fax back to: (866) 8**-****   OR email to: ******@*****.com</p>';
    echo '<p>Fitter Name: ________________________________________</p>';
    echo '<p>Comments:  _______________________________________________________________<br />';
    echo '_________________________________________________________________________</p>';
    echo '<p>The information contained in this email, together with any attachments, is intended only for the use of the individual or entity<br /> to which it is addressed. It may contain information that is confidential and prohibited from disclosure. If you are not the intended <br />';
    echo 'recipient, you are hereby notified that any dissemination, or copying, of this message or any attachment is strictly prohibited.</br> If you have received this message<br /> in error, please notify the original sender immediately by phone or by return email, </br>';
    echo 'and delete this email, along with any attachments. <br />Receipt by anyone other than the intended recipient is not</br> a waiver of any privileged information. </p>'; 

}

$body=ob_get_contents(); 
ob_end_clean(); 

#$body = "** It is Imperative that you respond to this email. When you receive this please print it out, sign your name and store number and fax the form to ***-***-1161**<br /><br /><br />";
#$body .= "Name: <br /><br />Store #:";


$headers = 'From: Visual Footcare Technologies *****@****.com'.$eol; 
$headers .= 'Reply-To: Visual Footcare Technologies *****@*****.com'.$eol; 
$headers .= 'Return-Path: Visual Footcare Technologies <mcooper@visualfootcare.com>'.$eol;     // these two to set reply address 
#$headers .= 'Cc: ******@*****.com'.$eol;
$headers .= "Message-ID:<".$now." TheSystem@".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].">".$eol; 
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP v".phpversion().$eol;           // These two to help avoid spam-filters 

$mime_boundary=md5(time()); 
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0'.$eol; 
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=\"".$mime_boundary."\"".$eol; 
$msg = ""; 


$msg .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative".$eol; 

$msg .= "--".$mime_boundary.$eol; 
$msg .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1".$eol; 
$msg .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit".$eol; 
$msg .= $body.$eol.$eol; 

$msg .= "--".$mime_boundary."--".$eol.$eol;   // finish with two eol's for better security. see Injection.
```

then a standard mail(......) code to send the email and then ending the loop.

hope that makes sense.

Comment: "random blank emails" i don't get it

Comment: had u tried  if ($tot_ord_ins_prt != ''){  ?

Answer (score 0):

try changing this

```
if ($tot_ord_ins_prt !== 0)
```

to

```
if ($tot_ord_ins_prt !== false)
```

Answer (score 0):

**MIME header blocks must be terminated by a blank line**, even when used in a multi-part section.  I don't know what you mean by "random", but I suspect that "blank emails" could be the result of your message body being interpreted as invalid MIME headers.

Insert a blank line between the last MIME header and your message body:

```
$msg .= $eol.$body.$eol.$eol;
```

If this doesn't help, you should probably show that "standard" `mail` line you mentioned.  Since it's the one that actually sends the email, I'm surprised you didn't include it.  You included a whole lot of other code.  It would be good to see what you do with the two strings, `$headers` and `$msg`.

Comment: # SEND THE EMAIL 

    $mail_sent = @mail( $emailaddress, $emailsubject, $msg, $headers ); 
    //if the message is sent successfully print "Mail sent". Otherwise print "Mail failed" 
    echo $mail_sent ? "<span style='padding-left:10px; font-family:Arial'>Report for Store: " . $Store . " was sucessfully sent to: " . $emailaddress . ".</span><br />" : "<span style='padding-left:10px; font-family:Arial'>Sorry but the email could not be sent to: " . $emailaddress . ".<br /></span>";

Comment: #Email Code

    # Is the OS Windows or Mac or Linux 
    if trtoupper(substr(PHP_OS,0,3)=='WIN')) { 
    $eol="\r\n"; 
    } elseif (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS,0,3)=='MAC')) { 
    $eol="\r"; 
    } else { 
    $eol="\n"; 
    }